# Help me understand this adware (compute-1.amazonaws.com)

Tags: malware, spyware

I ran TCPdump on my Macbook and saw a lot of communication going back and forth between 10.239.68.143 and compute-1.amazonaws.com.  I looked up my private IP address with `ifconfig` and found that that address is indeed mine and not someone else's.  I also did a Google search on compute-1.amazonaws.com and it looks like it's an adware that infects certain web pages.  Apparently whenever I have certain web pages open, those pages are sending messages back to the amazonaws server.

I would like to understand this adware better.  I want to understand how to get rid of it, but I also want to understand how it works.  What exactly is it doing, and how can I tell which page it is that's infected?  What is this adware?  Is it basically a virus that infects web pages?  Also, is there any way of knowing where the adware came from, how it got on my computer?

Comment: `compute-1.amazonaws.com` is just a server and not an adware source, specifically. Could you include in your question the source of the opinion that it is adware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

compute-1.amazonaws.com  is just part of the amazon cloud services. Anybody can rent resources there so that domain is not necessarily associated with adware although of course it can also contain adware, malware but the majority is probably benign.

> Apparently whenever I have certain web pages open, those pages are sending messages back to the amazonaws server.

It is very common that companies rent resources in the amazon cloud to easily adapt their computing power to the current load. It is nothing to worry about and it is not an indicator that you are infected with adware or malware. See also [What is s3.amazonaws.com, and why is Chrome blocking it?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85264/what-is-s3-amazonaws-com-and-why-is-chrome-blocking-it) for a similar question or read [here](https://aws.amazon.com/) for details about the amazon cloud services.